# How can I access to HDFS file system in the latest Tensorflow 2.6.0?

Tags: hdfs, tensorflow2.0

I recently upgraded the tensorflow version used in my program to the recently released 2.6.0, but I ran into a trouble.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

pattern = 'hdfs://mypath'
print(tf.io.gfile.glob(pattern))
```

The above API throws an exception in version 2.6:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnimplementedError: File system scheme'hdfs' not implemented (file:xxxxx)
```

Then I checked the [relevant implementation code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blame/master/tensorflow/core/platform/env.h#L653) and found that the official recommendation is to use `tensorflow/io` to access hdfs, and the environment variable `TF_USE_MODULAR_FILESYSTEM` is provided to use legacy access support. Since my code is more complex and difficult to refactor in a short time, I tried to use this environment variable, but it still failed.

In general, my questions are:

1. In the latest version of tensorflow, if "tfio" is not used, how can I still access the HDFS file?
2. If "tfio" must be used, what is the equivalent code call to `tf.io.gfile.glob`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL.DR. Install `tensorflow-io` and import it**.

After some tossing, I found a solution (it may be the official recommended way):

Since v2.6.0, Tensorflow no longer provides HDFS, GCS and other file system support in the framework, but transfers these support to the [Tensorflow/IO](https://github.com/tensorflow/io) project.

Therefore, in future versions, to have the support of HDFS, GCS and other file systems, **you only need to install tensorflow-io and import it to the training program**:

```sh
$ pip install tensorflow-io

$ cat test.py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_io as tfio

print(tf.io.gfile.glob('hdfs://...'))

$ CLASSPATH=$(${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop classpath --glob) python test.py
```

It will load libtensorflow_io.so and libtensorflow_io_plugins.so, which contains the implementation and registration logic of each extras file system:

```py
# tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py
core_ops = LazyLoader("core_ops", "libtensorflow_io.so")
try:
    plugin_ops = _load_library("libtensorflow_io_plugins.so", "fs")
except NotImplementedError as e:
    warnings.warn("unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: {}".format(e))
    # Note: load libtensorflow_io.so imperatively in case of statically linking
    try:
        core_ops = _load_library("libtensorflow_io.so")
        plugin_ops = _load_library("libtensorflow_io.so", "fs")
    except NotImplementedError as e:
        warnings.warn("file system plugins are not loaded: {}".format(e))
```

Ref:

- [Remove hdfs as support has been moved to modular file systems](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/51033)
- [Remove AWS files as s3 support is now in modular file system](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/51032)
- [SIG IO Meeting Notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CB51yJxns5WA4Ylv89D-a5qReiGTC0GYum6DU-9nKGo/edit#)

Comment: How to access HDFS from C++ API?

Comment: Will the other functions like `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` work too just with this import? It works with GCS without any other imports, but when I'm switching to AWS S3, it shows `Unimplemented Error`